# Experiences MozBackup for back-up Mozilla data

Tags: backup, firefox

Does anyone know if [MozBackup](http://mozbackup.jasnapaka.com/) is still updated? The News section speaks about the latest release with date December 13th, 2009

I want to back-up my Thunderbird e-mail messages.

Comment: From the [FAQ](http://superuser.com/faq#dontask) `your motivation for asking the question is “I would like to participate in a discussion about ______”, then you should not be asking here...`

Comment: Closed? Discussion??? I just want to know if this tool is still maintained. It's a yes/no question.

Comment: Fair enough, you started the question which "does anyone have any experience with MozBackup" .. which almost leads to a discussion. Reopened it. @waanders

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a brand new version!

March 29th, 2011, MozBackup 1.5.1 released

Answer (score 1):

It still works fine in my experience.

I used it for firefox and thunderbird when I moved into a new computer about 6 months ago.